# Moment of inertia of orbiting sphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, moment-of-inertia

Is the moment of inertia of a sphere orbiting some object equal to the moment of inertia of a point mass at the same distance away from the object?

Comment: You may use the parallel-axis theorem easily in this case due to the symmetry of the problem. You can also use the inertia tensor at the center point of the sphere and translate it accordingly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem

Answer (score 2):

No.

An extended rigid body having (intrinsic) mass moment of inertia $I_C$ at its center of mass would have a mass moment of inertia about another point *A* equal to

$$ I_A = I_C + m \ell_{AC}^2 $$

where $\ell_{AC}$ is the distance between *A* and the center of mass *C*.